# How can I solve Android SDK problem for flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I had been using Android Studio for developing android projects. Later I downloaded flutter plugins to continue with flutter. But I keep having Android SDK problem and I can't run any flutter project neither on Android studio nor on VScode. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

[Flutter_Doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cElym.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your Android SDK Path Like this: 
[image: Android SDK path]

and your Flutter SDK path should appear here as:
[image: Flutter SDK path]